# How can I avoid having to manually obtain OAuth 2.0 authorization codes for Youtube Analytics API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I'd like to set up my code to run daily but the only roadblock is OAuth. I have to login to my Google account each time I run my code to obtain the authorization code to access my Youtube data. I'm trying to find a way to either store the authorization code automatically without me needing to follow the url and manually copy it, or to create some sort of credentials that I can store in my script to use anytime authorization is needed.

```
youtubeAnalytics = get_service()

result = execute_api_request(
    youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
    ids='channel==MINE',
    startDate=format_week,
    endDate=format_today,
    metrics='estimatedMinutesWatched,views,likes,subscribersGained',
    dimensions='video',
    sort='-views',
    maxResults=20
 )
```

This line is what prompts the url I need to access for the authorization code.

I was unable to find documentation to support the idea that storing credentials may be possible without the ues of OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The Analytics API accesses non-public data, so the channel's owner/content owner **must** complete the OAuth2 flow to authorize your app to call the Analytics API on their behalf.

You can use the `offline` parameter during the authorization request; in this case, you will also get a `refresh_token` that will be used to regenerate the `access_token` when it expires, without needing the user's interaction. The official Google API Clients take care of the regeneration for you. You would just need to persist both tokens somewhere.

The implementations depending on your app type and language can be found here [YouTube > Analytics and Reporting APIs > Implement OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization)